# How to return an Error from a generic method

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

The title doesn't describe the issue very well so let me explain my problem.

I have a generic function to consume API's via HTTP GET calls. Which looks like this:

```
public async static Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string Base_Url,string relative_URL, Utility.UriExtensions.NameValueCollection Params, Utility.UriExtensions.NameValueCollection headers = null)
    {
        Uri CompleteURL = new Uri(Base_Url + relative_URL, UriKind.Absolute);
        if (Params != null)
            CompleteURL = Utility.UriExtensions.CreateUriWithQuery(CompleteURL, Params);
        if(headers!=null)
        {
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> k in headers)
            {
                if (ApiHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ContainsKey(k.Key))
                    ApiHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders[k.Key] = k.Value;
                else
                    ApiHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(k.Key, k.Value);
            }
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("GET : " + CompleteURL);
        using (var response = await ApiHttpClient.GetAsync(CompleteURL).AsTask(cancellationToken.Token).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            string responseData="";
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                Debug.WriteLine(responseData);

                JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
                settings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTime;
                settings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate;
                settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
                settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None;
            }

            try
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseData);
            }
            catch
            {
                // Error
                Debug.WriteLine(
                "Error occurred, the status code is: {0} and Content : {1}",
                response.StatusCode, response.Content);
            }
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

In case of error, the error is handled inside catch body. I want to return these Error informations like StatusCode and Content of response when this happens. But I am unable to make any changes to this generic function. How should handle this.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can use [`out`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) parameter, which you will pass in your method:

```
public async static Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string Base_Url,string relative_URL, Utility.UriExtensions.NameValueCollection Params, Utility.UriExtensions.NameValueCollection headers = null, out StatusCode code)


StatusCode statusCode;
GetAsync<Foo>(..., out statusCode);
```

Comment: Damn, that's a really nice idea. Thanks

Comment: Hey one problem. You can't have async methods with ref or out parameters, So close